# Restkit 20 failed to match all (0) response descriptors

Tags: restkit-0.20

I don't know if failed to match all (0) response descriptors means there are 0 descriptors?

Here are some logs:

PATH:
search/patients?q=qwer&start=0&max=40

BASE URL:
https://amb.XXX.com/

RKRESPONSEDESCRIPTORS:

```
(
    "<RKResponseDescriptor: 0xaaca6a0 method=(GET) pathPattern=search/patients?q=qwer&start=0&max=40 keyPath=(null) statusCodes=(null) : <RKObjectMapping:0xaab4f80 objectClass=NSMutableDictionary propertyMappings=(\n    \"<RKAttributeMapping: 0x9edf630 final_page => finalPage>\",\n    \"<RKRelationshipMapping: 0xaac9750 results => patientSearchResultDetails>\"\n)>>"
)


restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:378 Executing mapping operation for representation: {
    "final_page" = 1;
    results =     (
                {
            age = "39 years";
            "date_of_birth" = "1975-01-15";
            gender = Male;
            mrns =             {
                effective =                 (
                    10000423
                );
                ineffective =                 (
                );
            };
            "name_full_formatted" = "DOE, PETER";
            "person_id" = 1390007;
            "phone_numbers" =             {
                home = "(816) 555-5555";
            };
            "preferred_name" = PETE;
            "primary_care_provider" =             {
                name = "Test, Physician4";
            };
        }
    );
}
```

and targetObject: (null)
2014-04-16 12:45:03.263 IONShell[31463:4f03] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMapperOperation.m:404 Finished performing object mapping. Results: (null)
2014-04-16 12:45:03.264 IONShell[31463:4e1b] E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:208 GET 'https://amb.XXX.com/search/patients?q=qwer&start=0&max=40' (200 OK / 0 objects) [request=1.5086s mapping=0.0000s total=1.5143s]:
error=Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 "No response descriptors match the response loaded." UserInfo=0xa9eead0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://amb.XXX.com/search/patients?q=qwer&start=0&max=40, NSLocalizedFailureReason=A 200 response was loaded from the URL 'https://amb.XXX.com/search/patients?q=qwer&start=0&max=40', which failed to match all (0) response descriptors:, NSLocalizedDescription=No response descriptors match the response loaded., keyPath=null, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://amb.XXX.com/search/patients?q=qwer&start=0&max=40, NSUnderlyingError=0xa9e3f40 "No mappable object representations were found at the key paths searched."}

Does (0) mean my RKObjectManager has no response descriptors? Or am I missing something else? This is driving me nuts.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Figure it out. I needed to send down the query part of the string as params.

```
 NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:queryString, @"q", start, @"start", maxCount, @"max", nil];


    [self loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"search/patients" params:params objectMapping:mapping]
```

Comment: You saved me!!! I was 3 days with a similar trouble and it was too that I was sending parameters in the query string. Once I've removed from the path it started working. Thanks a lot for sharing your solution.